# PyDev Debugger Warnings in PyCharm: Unable to find real location for modules and slower performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, virtualenv

I am currently debugging my Python code in PyCharm, and I've come across a series of warnings from the PyDev debugger. The key messages I'm seeing are:

"This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)"
"The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints."
A series of "Unable to find real location for: ..." messages
The full log of the warnings is here.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pydev debugger: CRITICAL WARNING: This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)
pydev debugger: The debugger may still function, but it will work slower and may miss breakpoints.
pydev debugger: Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected to pydev debugger (build 221.5921.27)
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen codecs>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen zipimport>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen _collections_abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen os>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <string>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen abc>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen io>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen posixpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <frozen genericpath>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr attr._make.Attribute>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr._make.Attribute>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr._make.Attribute>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr attr._make._CountingAttr>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr._make._CountingAttr>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr attr._make.Factory>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr._make.Factory>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr._make.Factory>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr attr._make._AndValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr._make._AndValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr._make._AndValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr._make._AndValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._InstanceOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._InstanceOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._InstanceOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._MatchesReValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._MatchesReValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._MatchesReValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._ProvidesValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._ProvidesValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._ProvidesValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._OptionalValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._OptionalValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._OptionalValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._InValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._InValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._InValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._IsCallableValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._IsCallableValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._IsCallableValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._DeepIterable>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._DeepIterable>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._DeepIterable>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._DeepMapping>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._DeepMapping>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._DeepMapping>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._NumberValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._NumberValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._NumberValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._MaxLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._MaxLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._MaxLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._MinLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._MinLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._MinLengthValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._SubclassOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._SubclassOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._SubclassOfValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq attr.validators._NotValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash attr.validators._NotValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr.validators._NotValidator>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr attr._version_info.VersionInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init attr._version_info.VersionInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.helpers.ProxyInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.helpers.ProxyInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.helpers.ProxyInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.helpers.ProxyInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.helpers.MimeType>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.helpers.MimeType>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.helpers.MimeType>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.helpers.MimeType>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.helpers.ETag>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.helpers.ETag>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.helpers.ETag>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.helpers.ETag>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.client_reqrep.ContentDisposition>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.client_reqrep.ContentDisposition>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.client_reqrep.ContentDisposition>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.client_reqrep.ContentDisposition>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.client_reqrep.RequestInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.client_reqrep.RequestInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.client_reqrep.RequestInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.client_reqrep.RequestInfo>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.client_reqrep.ConnectionKey>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.client_reqrep.ConnectionKey>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.client_reqrep.ConnectionKey>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.client_reqrep.ConnectionKey>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestChunkSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestChunkSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestChunkSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestChunkSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceResponseChunkReceivedParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceResponseChunkReceivedParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceResponseChunkReceivedParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceResponseChunkReceivedParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestExceptionParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestExceptionParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestExceptionParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestExceptionParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestRedirectParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestRedirectParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestRedirectParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestRedirectParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionQueuedEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionCreateEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionReuseconnParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionReuseconnParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionReuseconnParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceConnectionReuseconnParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostStartParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsResolveHostEndParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheHitParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheHitParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheHitParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheHitParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheMissParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheMissParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheMissParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceDnsCacheMissParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestHeadersSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestHeadersSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestHeadersSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.tracing.TraceRequestHeadersSentParams>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated repr aiohttp.client.ClientTimeout>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated eq aiohttp.client.ClientTimeout>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated hash aiohttp.client.ClientTimeout>
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: <attrs generated init aiohttp.client.ClientTimeout>
2023-09-20 16:16:12 INFO     AWS Environment: staging
```

### Details of my environment:

PyCharm version: [PyCharm 2022.1.3 (Community Edition)]

Runtime version: [11.0.15+10-b2043.56 aarch64]

Python version: [3.11.3]

Operating System: [MacOS Ventura 13.5.2]

Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it? I'm concerned about the potential slower performance of the debugger and missing breakpoints, which can significantly hinder my debugging process.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with my configuration

- Windows 11
- Python 3.10.5 (installed from zip), working on django project
- PyCharm 2023.2.5

As said in another thread I tried to réinstall python :

- Delete venv
- Re install python 3.10 with latest windows installer available (3.10.11)
- Re create venv / re install requirements

And it works fine ... and I don't know why.